# Woocommerce order date-time in customer processing order email notification

Tags: php, datetime, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

Is there a way to get the exact order date and time to show up in woocommerce emails? So far I am using this to get the order date:

```
<?php printf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?>
```

I get the correct date however no timestamp when the order was placed. How do I add the exact time stamp?

Something like this:

Order NO. XXXX (placed on February 25, 2018 10:06PM EST)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is **4 different date cases** when an order is placed *(where `$order` is an instance of the [**`WC_order`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) Object)* depending on order status, on the payment method used and on Woocommerce regarding behavior:

- The creation date: `$order->get_date_created()`
- The modification date: `$order->get_date_modified()`
- The paid date: `$order->get_date_paid()`
- The completed date: `$order->get_date_completed()`

All this 4 orders different dates are [**`WC_DateTime`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_DateTime.html) objects *(instances)* where you can use available [**`WC_DateTime`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_DateTime.html) methods.

To get the correct format to have something like: 
**Order NO. XXXX (placed on February 25, 2018 10:06PM EST)** 
… you will use the for example the following:

```
$date_modified = $order->get_date_modified();
echo sprintf( '<p>Order NO. %s (placed on <time>%s</time>)</p>', 
    $order->get_order_number( ), 
    $date_modified->date("F j, Y, g:i:s A T")
);
```

> If you want to use `get_date_paid()` or `get_date_completed()` methods you should need to do it carefully, testing that the `WC_DateTime` object exist before trying to display it…

```
$date_paid = $order->get_date_paid();
if( ! empty( $date_paid) ){
    echo sprintf( '<p>Order NO. %s (placed on <time>%s</time>)</p>', 
        $order->get_order_number( ), 
        $date_paid->date("F j, Y, g:i:s A T")
    );
}
```

As you don't specify where exactly specifically you want this to be displayed for customer processing order email notification, I will give you an example of hooked function that you can use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'custom_processing_order_notification', 1, 4 );
function custom_processing_order_notification( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Only for processing email notifications to customer
    if( ! 'customer_processing_order' == $email->id ) return;

    $date_modified = $order->get_date_modified();
    $date_paid = $order->get_date_paid();

    $date =  empty( $date_paid ) ? $date_modified : $date_paid;

    echo sprintf( '<p>Order NO. %s (placed on <time>%s</time>)</p>',
        $order->get_order_number( ),
        $date->date("F j, Y, g:i:s A T")
    );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much, really appreciate your time and effort! =)